# Error when I try to print value of an openssl_csr_get_subject

Tags: php, html, forms, ssl, csr

I'm trying to decode a .csr sent by a form. An example of my snippet could be found below:

```
    $csr=$_POST["elcsr"];
    $data=openssl_csr_get_subject($csr);
    $email = array_values($data)[6];
    echo $email;
```

But my attempt to print email fails with the following error:

```
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given in C:\wamp644\www\proyecto1\back-end\castellano\decodificado.php on line 16
```

I don't know what's happening...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you could see in the official PHP documentation of [openssl_csr_get_subject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-get-subject.php), this function may return false if error occurred. So you need to check and validate what was posted to your script in "elcsr" before submitting it to that function.